# fraction slider not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I've downloaded Fraction Slider from @jacksbox and have gone through the documentation countless times now and cannot figure out why my slider won't show the effects it's supposed to. This is the site I'm working on: http://pacificdesignacademy.com/NEW/2 and this is an example of what the slider is supposed to do: http://jacksbox.de/stuff/jquery-fractionslider/.

Here is the path to my js: ../NEW/2/fractionslider/jquery.fractionslider.js

And here is the path to my css ../NEW/2/fractionslider/fractionslider.css

All of the images are just stacking on top of one another regardless of me defining overflow:hidden on the containing element.

Not sure what else to do here, so any help is greatly appreciated. I'm supposed to launch this site September 1st... eep!

Thanks!

Comment: you should post the relevant code here in your question

Comment: Whenever you develop with javascript you should have your browser's console open (Ctrl+Shift+J), that's where all errors are logged, I've updated my answer with new insight on your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple check in the browser's console showed you have a syntax error on line 594 of your page. You have a closing parenthesis instead of an opening brace.

**UPDATE** After you fixed that, you're now getting the error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

I suggest you move your code and place it after you've included both jQuery and the slider plugin, so your page should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fractionslider/jquery.fractionslider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    $('.slider').fractionSlider({
    'fullWidth':            true,
    'controls':             true, 
    'pager':                true,
    'responsive':           true,
    'dimensions':           "1200,400",
    'increase':             false,
    'pauseOnHover':         true
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an opening parenthesis when calling the plugin.

Change

```
$('.slider').fractionSlider()
```

To

```
$('.slider').fractionSlider({
```

On line 593

Comment: Thank you, I fixed that but the slider still does not function. Any other ideas?

Comment: @matty no need to post the same information I did 10 minutes before you

Answer (score -1):

FractionSlider is garbish! Use [LiquidSlider](http://liquidslider.com/) instead!
What one doesn't have but exist in the other:

- well formated object oriented code,
- automatic hardware acceleration with the new CSS3 transforms if the browser supports it (no js animation here!),
- keyboard navigation,
- hash linking where user can bookmark a specific slide or land to a page that opens slider to a specific slide,
- many effects,
- mobile 'swap' support
- user extensible.

Of course it uses some other libraries and code snipets 'stolen' from here and there (https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/09/detecting-and-generating-css-animations-in-javascript/ but actually it's reduntant as the use of Moderniz library in responsive designs makes the detection as simple as a one-line command, http://easings.net/ for the easing equations, https://daneden.me/animate/ for the transformations etc.)

The idea behind FractionSlider is indeed unique but the implementation sucks!